# How to longitudinally concatenate/append columns of a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

There are many examples of how to concatenate columns element by element, but I can't find an example where columns are concatenated sequentially. I can write an example with a loop:

```
tst <- cbind.data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
names(tst) <- c("A","B")
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

vec <- c()
for (i in names(tst)){
  vec <- c(vec,tst[,i])
}
```

> vec
>   [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

In other words, I want to create a vector with all the columns of the data frame appended one after the other.
The solution above works, but my question is: is there a way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we can use `unlist` to convert to a `vector`

```
vec1 <- unlist(tst, use.names = FALSE)
identical(vec, vec1)
#[1] TRUE
```